# Looking for a paperback black/white ghost story anthology kids/young teens book from the 70's/80's

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, young-adult, horror

I am looking for this one particular paper-back book that I found at a local Book Traders as a kid (way back, must have been early 90s). One of the things I distinctly remember about the front cover artwork was the ghost of a princess(or bride) where she's floating around with her hands chopped off. There is like 3 or 4 other stories in this book. Another story in this book was this hermit that gets accused of a crime that he didn't commit, but he had done a similar crime which he wasn't convicted of that one. The short story ends with him hanging himself in his jail cell. This character is also on the cover of the book.

That's about all that I remember of this book. It has a ton of illustrations in that it seemed more like a graphic novel. All of the illustrations were in black and white. If anyone has any info or possible clues to what this book is please let me know. This is a quest I've been on the search for the past 20 years of my life. I know it sounds silly, but this book was so well-written and left a huge impression on me as a kid. If anyone has any clues, please let me know. Thank-you.

Comment: http://www.scaryforkids.com/stories-to-tell/ ?

Comment: Fiction, I assume, rather than "real life" stories?

Comment: Yes it is fiction.

Comment: No it's not Scary Stories to Tell In The Dark. 

Also the front artwork was color while the inside illustrations were black/white.

Comment: do the illustrations look like these: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=charles+keeping&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXs6CUs4PNAhVEmpQKHQDICE0Q_AUIBygB&biw=765&bih=570